# How to handle mobile number recycling by telephone companies?

Tags: mobile, recycle

I need to implement one user ID for one user. After looking around, closest I can see is using mobile phone numbers to text. Assuming this is best available method How to handle mobile number recycling by telephone companies? Any ideas?

Following is best one that attempted to answer on how to implement one ID for one person-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964664/account-verification-only-1-account-per-person

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Back when I worked for a marketing client, our business was based on determining whether two people were the same - "our records show Bob Smith. Is the Robert Smith who responded the same as Bob Smith?"

Our data could be segmented into name, method of contact (address, phone, email) and relationship (Alonzo works for Square Tires Inc). Once the data had been scrubbed/standardized, we would then compare that entity to possible matches in the system. Matching on a single segment was insufficient to categorize as a match. We required two different segment matches for an entity to be matched to another.  This was important as matching phone and address might yield different members of the same household. Depending on your criteria, that might be sufficient but generally it is not.

With all that said, I don't think you have enough information to make a semi-authoritative guess as to whether phone number 1234567 is the original user or a person who has had their phone number reassigned. I would attempt to capture more personally identifiable information about the entity registering the phone number. The registration of an existing phone number with different PII would not cause the original holder of the number to become invalidated, it merely signifies that a new user has come onboard. Until you get enough information back about the original holder of that number having a new method of contact, you should probably retain the association to the phone number. It could be the case the second registrant supplied a bogus number or either applicant fat-fingered their number and you wouldn't know which was accurate.

You can still run into issues with say corporate issued mobile phones. A company has a pool of phones they distribute to folks. People quit and get hired and those phone numbers remain the domain of the company but are assigned to people that then register for your service.

Hope this helps give you some starting points for solving the problem.